# Where can I get data on deep space satellites or probes like voyager 1

Tags: communication, deep-space, pioneer

I am doing a research on deep space communication. I need data on any of the man made deep space probes like voyager 1. I need the probe's transmitter power, received power on earth, Signal to noise ratio (SNR), Bit error rate of communication, received energy per bit, path loss data and several other communication data.
I need this data over a duration of at least one year to develop a good model for my research.

Comment: Voyager data is stored at the [NSSDCA](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/displayDataset.action?spacecraftId=1977-076A), but that's the science data, not the telemetry. I haven't come across any online telemetry archive for Voyager, you may have to contact the Voyager science team.

Comment: I think the SPICE toolkit is the thing you are seaching for in case you want to look to Solar System probes databases https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/spiceconcept.html. You also have the visualization tool of SPICE called Cosmographia: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/cosmographia.html The data for the Voyagers is located here: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/VOYAGER/kernels/

Comment: Thank you. what I need is a place to get telemetry data of any deep space probe or satellite like voyager 1. I need this information to be able to do empirical modelling of the deep space channel. If you do have other suggestions. I am open to them

Answer (score 2):

JPL operates the "Deep Space Communications and Navigation Center of Excellence" they call "DESCANSO" with [this home page](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/). They publish (online) a huge trove of information on general characteristics of deep space communications systems and also specifics — sometimes in excruciating detail! — about many of the deep space missions JPL has operated.